# MySQL - foreign key constrained by primary key in same table, error #1452

Tags: mysql

I created a table where `cat_parent_id` is a foreign key is constrained by the primary key `cat_id`, using this:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    cat_id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    cat_parent_ID SMALLINT,
    cat_name VARCHAR(40)

    INDEX cat_id(cat_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(cat_id) REFERENCES categories(cat_id),      
);
```

When I try to insert a record where `cat_parent_ID` is `NULL`, I get the error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myDatabase`.`categories`, CONSTRAINT `categories_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`cat_id`))
```

How can the foreign key constraint fail when there is no foreign key to begin with? Is the constraint only possible if null is not allowed?

I can only insert records successfully if I disable the constraint, which is not what I want. I need the `parent_id` to be optional, and if it has a value then it be an existing `cat_id` only

Comment: Did you mean to put the FK on `cat_parent_id`?

Comment: @AaronKent yep that is what I meant to do... thx for pointing out the fix

Comment: Awesome. Would you mind marking my answer as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create a circular foreign key, which will prevent any insertion into the table.

```
FOREIGN KEY(cat_id) REFERENCES categories(cat_id),
```

EDIT: Perhaps you meant to put the PK on `cat_parent_id`?

Answer (score 0):

You have one root record which doesn't have a parent.  For this one, you must first disable foreign key constraints.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Insert the record.

Then don't forget to re-enble foreign key constraints

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Then from now own, make sure your inserts include an existing parent.

> How can the foreign key constraint fail when there is no foreign key
>   to begin with? Is the constraint only possible if null is not allowed?

If you want to add other records which do not have a FK value, make sure that NULL is allowed.